# Equality Between Base 10 and Base 16

Tags: bash, hex, mips

From my textbook:

[image]

What does it mean when it says 37 subscript(16) = 55 subscript(10)?

Comment: Bash says they are equal: `echo $[5 * 10 + 5] $[3 * 16 + 7]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means 37 base 16 (Hexadecimal), and 55 base 10 (Decimal).  The 0x preceding a number denotes that it is base 16 hexadecimal.

To see how they are equal lets first look at the place values of 55

```
 5, 5 (digits)
10, 1 (place values)
```

They are 10 to the power of the number of places over they are so 10^0 = 1 for the ones, and 10^1 = 10 for the tens.

You have a 5 in the ones place giving you 5, and 5 in the tens place giving you 50 when you add them together you get 55.

```
5 * 10 = 50
5 * 1 = 5

5 + 50 = 55
```

The 37 is in Hexadecimal which means its base is 16 so the place values are 16 to the power of the number of places over which gives you

```
 3, 7 (digits)
16, 1 (place values)

3 * 16 = 48
7 * 1 = 7

48 + 7 = 55
```

Because the Hexadecimal system requires 16 unique numerals it uses the letters a-f as well

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  a,  b,  c,  d,  e,  f
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

Also because you might see these 0b denotes base 2 (Binary), and 0o denotes base 8 (Octal).

Comment: I added more information, hope it was helpful :) @NoName